# Change a link using plain JavaScript and selecting the element with a compound CSS selection

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to change a link using plain JavaScript and by selecting the element with a compound selection. 
Is it possible? If so, how would I do that?

Here is the css selection

```
#ves-accordion > li.level0.nav-living-room.active.parent > a > span
```

This is what I tried, but failed.

```
document.querySelector(‘#ves-accordion > li.level0.nav-living-room.active.parent > a > span’).href="link.html";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to target the `a` element, not the `span` element. Anchors can be links. Spans cannot.